# Handling the case where a web service is down in Android App

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I'm a beginner.  I'm creating an Android app that uses an Azure web service which returns SOAP.  The address to the web service is *http://XXXXXXXX.cloudapp.net/Service.svc/*.

I'm using ksoap2 to consume the service.  I would like to cover all bases.  I have handled the case where there is no internet connectivity in the Android device.  However, I would like to handle the unlikely case where the web service is down.

How do people go about doing this?  DO I use some sort of exception handler in the catch? Which catch?  Thanks in advance.  I'm using an AsyncTask:

```
  public class getSetWSDate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

{

```
   ProgressDialog dialog;

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPreExecute();

       dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Please wait...");

   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, DATE_METHOD_NAME); 

               SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
               envelope.dotNet = true;
               envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

               HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
               ht.debug = true;

               ht.call(SOAP_ACTION_DATE, envelope);


               final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
               final String strDate = response.toString();


               SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date webServiceDate = new Date(); //"2013-07-07 10:00:00" 
                try {

                    webServiceDate = (Date)dateFormat.parse(strDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
       syncDateDatasource.open();


   syncDateDatasource.createDate(webServiceDate);
   syncDateDatasource.close();
       }        catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPostExecute(result);

       if(dialog.isShowing())
       {
           dialog.dismiss();
       }

       try {
         ....


       } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

   }
```

}